# How do I ad a javafx window to my java console application?

Tags: java, javafx

I seem to have hit a wall with the final pieces of my app that im working on.

I have created a standard Java application that is to be executed at the command line. This app uses one config file to receive parameters and executes using these parameters. At present this config file is hand crafted and I wish to add a gui layer to generate this now that ive finished the main code that executes at run time.

I have attempted to add (via netbeans) a new Empty FXML file but it complains in the controller class that the 'method does nto override or implement a method from a supertype'.

Any ideas what could be wrong?

thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You must have a class which implements an interface in the class definition but does not implement a method from the interface (or abstract class).

Comment: aha , thx. Ive also noticed (didnt see it due to the code folding) that the statement 'import javafx.fxml.Initializable;' has an error as its cant find the javafx support even though the project is set to use this...hmm...